# r makeCluster command used to work but now fails in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I have been using parallel code for at least the past three months. The key element is a slightly more complex version of `cl <- parallel::makeCluster(1)`. I hadn't used it since I updated to R 4.0 on my Mac. I tried it this morning and I get the following error with some delay after I run the command above.

```
Error in makePSOCKcluster(names = spec, ...) : 
  Cluster setup failed. 1 worker of 1 failed to connect.
```

I tried it in R from a terminal and it worked fine.

I had been using a slightly outdated version of RStudio so I downloaded and installed the latest version. I still get the same error message.

Some system stats - MacBook Pro running Catalina, RStudio version is now 1.2.5042. R version 4.0.0, Xcode 11.4.1

Comment: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/6692

Comment: The temporary solution for now until RStudio gets fixed, from the link @Axeman posted is to use `cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2, setup_strategy = "sequential")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The temporary solution for now until RStudio gets fixed, from the link @Axeman posted is to use cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2, setup_strategy = "sequential")